# DJANGO: Variables passed to templates by context manager not reflecting admin changes

Tags: python, django, apache

I have an issue when information is updated via the admin.

The variables product_list and shop_list are being called by my base.html template to fill some menus on every page of the site

On the home page, where the variables are fed threw views.py the changes are reflected immediately.

But on the other pages, which are being fed variables by context_manage.py the changes are not reflected until I reset apache, or maybe after some undefined period of time... definitely not in a reasonable amount of time anyways.

Why isn't the context manager working properly? And how can I ensure that the lists are updated across all pages upon admin input with out passing them individually to every single view?

view for index.html:

```
general = get_object_or_404(General, pk=1)
product_list = Product.objects.all()
shop_list = general.shop_set.all();
```

What's inside context_manage.py:

```
general = General.objects.get(pk=1)
product_list = Product.objects.all()
shop_list = general.shop_set.all();


def passProList(request):
    return {
        'product_list': product_list,
        'shop_list': shop_list,
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the definition of those variables into their own method or directly into `passProList`. Currently, they are being evaluated at the time the python file is compiled. You need them to be evaluated when they are accessed in the templates.

```
def get_pro_lists(pk):
    general = General.objects.get(pk=pk)
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    shop_list = general.shop_set.all()
    return product_list, shop_list


def passProList(request):
    product_list, shop_list = get_pro_lists(1)
    return {
        'product_list': product_list,
        'shop_list': shop_list,
    }
```

Comment: So, let me get this straight. In my program, passProList is called every time a view is filled to get the context but the variables it contains are set only once when the script is first compiled because the database calls outside of `passProList` only run once at that time... ie, when I reset apache. So by calling a function inside passProList that accesses the db, the db will be accessed everytime passProList is invoked?